# In a PDF, How to auto populate one field using other field text?

Tags: adobe, acrobat

I have a 54 pages PDF file. In this PDF, I have some fields like Full Name, the Phone number, etc that repeats more than 10 times. How can do like When I enter Full name one time and all of the remaining full name fields can be filled automatically using Adobe Acrobat?

I hope I asked my question clearly. Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is, when all properties of the field (font type, size, color, etc.) are the same, to simply copy the field to the other pages.

The field value is a so-called field level property, which will be the same for all instances of the field.

If you want to have only one place where the value can be entered, and the dependent fields should be read-only, you would have to have a different name for the entry field and display fields. In the entry field, you would then add the following line of code in either the Format or onBlur event:

```
this.getField("myDisplayFields").value = event.value ;
```

And that should push the value from the entry field to all fields named `myDisplayFields`.

And that's it…

Comment: Thank you @Max Wyss. I will try this one.